# Android Device Manager - Hyper-V not configured

Tags: android, windows

Trying to run and Android Device but says "*Hyper-V not configured*"

[image]

So I double-checking `systeminfo` says:

```
Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

Is there anything that needs to be installed first so the Android Device Manager can detect that there's a hypervisor?

Answer (score 6):

I ran in a similar problem even when the Hyper-V features were enabled in the `Turn Windows features on or off` dialog and the `Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors` was installed.

It turned out the `Windows Hypervisor Platform` was not enabled correctly.

Check the status of both Hyper-V and the Hypervisor by using the following (`PowerShell`) commands.

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName HypervisorPlatform -Online
```

If the status of one (or both) is `Disabled`, simply use the following command(s) to enabled it/them.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName HypervisorPlatform -All
```

[image: Example of enabling the disabled Hypervisor]

Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/troubleshooting#hyper-v-issues)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it.

I have AMD Ryzen CPU and I had to go to **Android SDKs and Tools**.
[image]

[image]

Then I went to the **Tools** tab -> **Extras**.
And here was **Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors**. I had to enable it as it was disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:
Right click on the Windows button and select 'Apps and Features'. Select Programs and Features on the right under related settings. Select Turn Windows Features on or off. Select Hyper-V and click OK.

For Linux: https://www.nakivo.com/blog/run-linux-hyper-v/

For Mac: https://www.parallels.com/blogs/hyper-v-mac/

Comment: The issue is the android emulator wont run on nested virtualization

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue too.

Make sure you have enabled Hyper-V **and** the Windows Hypervisor Platform in Apps & Features > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off.

I also needed to install the Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors as in MadTiger2409's answer.